# ¿Cómo puedo hacer una lista random con choice?

Tags: python, random

hice un programa en donde un número calcula el porcentaje de otro número. (Si el 15% de N es el 20% de Q....).
El programa funciona bien, solo que el problema surge al querer que las variables `op1` y `op2` hagan una combinación específica y hacerlas aleatorias para que sean elegidas al momento de imprimir:

```
from random import randint, choice
    
archivo=open('Porcentaje de x es y.txt', 'w')
letras, letras2=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M'], ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']

insert=int(input('Valor: '))
for i in range(1, insert+1):
    x,y=randint(1,100), randint(1,100)
    op1, op2=choice(letras), choice(letras2)
    if op1 != op2:
        print(f'{i}.- Si el {x}% de {op1} es igual al {y}% de {op2}. ¿Qué porcentaje de {op1} es {op2}?')
        archivo.write(f'{i}.- Si el {x}% de {op1} es igual al {y}% de {op2}. ¿Qué porcentaje de {op1} es {op2}?\n\n')

archivo.close()
```

Es decir, quiero que ocurra esta combinatoria:

```
    print(f'{i}.- Si el {x}% de {op1} es igual al {y}% de {op2}. ¿Qué porcentaje de {op1} es {op2}?')
    print(f'{i}.- Si el {x}% de {op1} es igual al {y}% de {op2}. ¿Qué porcentaje de {op2} es {op1}?')
    print(f'{i}.- Si el {x}% de {op2} es igual al {y}% de {op1}. ¿Qué porcentaje de {op1} es {op2}?')
    print(f'{i}.- Si el {x}% de {op1} es igual al {y}% de {op2}. ¿Qué porcentaje de {op1} es {op2}?')
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer aleatorias las variables `op1` y `op2` para que se pueda hacer esa combinación al imprimir?
Les agradezco mucho, saludos.

Comment: La función `choice` se usa para escoger alestoriamente un elemento de un conjunto, si quieres que se generen valores aleatorios sin tener que establecerlo solo usa `randint()` o `randrange()`

Comment: Me puedes poner un ejemplo, muchas gracias

Comment: revisando bien tu pregunta, con `choice(letras)` ya estas escogiendo una letra aleatoria, podrias describir mejor lo que quieres?

Comment: Por ejemplo: Cuando se imprime, tal cual y puse mi código, siempre imprime esto: `1.- Si el 85% de G es igual al 74% de K. ¿Qué porcentaje de G es K?` y bueno, yo quiero que las letras por ejemplo `G` y `K` cambien de lugar algo así:
`1.- Si el 85% de K es igual al 74% de G. ¿Qué porcentaje de G es K?` o así 
`1.- Si el 85% de G es igual al 74% de K. ¿Qué porcentaje de K es G?`, observa la posición de las letras mayúsculas, quiero que cambien del lugar y sean random, no estáticas

Comment: osea que no esten en el mismo orden en la oracion?

Comment: De hecho, no quiero que estén en orden, quiero que sean aleatorias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok para hacer que el orden sea aleatorio vamos a hacer lo mismo que se haria para escojer un numero aleatorio, solo necesitaremos cambiar alguna cosas

```py
#tu codigo
op1, op2=choice(letras), choice(letras2)

#nuevo codigo

#aqui ponemos en una lista las 2 Letras escojidas aleatoriamente,ejemplo A y C
op = [choice(letras), choice(letras)]

#añadido
#con esto escojeremos cualquier posicion del arreglo 
pos = randint(0,len(op)-1) # randint escojera un numero entre los especificados
pos2 = randint(0,len(op)-1)
```

Y listo, ahora solo añadimos esto a tu codigo

```
from random import randint, choice

archivo=open('Porcentaje de x es y.txt', 'w')
#como extra simplificamos esta linea, ya que las letras seran las mismas
letras =['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']

insert=int(input('Valor: '))

for i in range(1, insert+1):
    x,y=randint(1,100), randint(1,100)
    op = [choice(letras), choice(letras)]
    pos = randint(0,len(op)-1)
    pos2 = randint(0,len(op)-1)
    if op[0] != op[1]:
        print(f'{i}.- Si el {x}% de {op[pos]} es igual al {y}% de {op[pos-1]}. ¿Qué porcentaje de {op[pos2]} es {op[pos2-1]}?')
     #con pos-1 escojeremos un elemento diferente al asignado anteriormente
     #lo bueno de esto es que trabajaos con un array de 2 elementos 
archivo.close()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!